# Duration weighted Optimal Matching Algorithm using R

Tags: r, stata, traminer, sequence-analysis

Besides the [ado](http://teaching.sociology.ul.ie/seqanal/) provided by Brendan Halpin for Stata, is there a way to pursue an Optimal Matching using the R-package `TraMineR` which weights OM’s elementary operations inversely with episode length [1]?

<sub>[1]: See Halpin, B. (2010) 'Optimal Matching Analysis and Life-Course Data: The Importance of Duration', Sociological Methods & Research 38(3): 365–388.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TraMineR` does not (yet) compute `Duration weighted Optimal Matching Algorithm`. Unfortunatly, this distance measure does not garantee the triangular inequality (in French, see chapter 2 of http://archive-ouverte.unige.ch/vital/access/manager/Repository/unige:22054). Depending on the distance analysis procedure (clustering) you plan to use, this may be problematic.

Comment: Aren't there some cluster algorithms which do not rely on triangle inequality? Besides, there is a recent [master's thesis](http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2:563483) which presents a modified k-means algorithm without triangle inequality. Maybe, this will be more interesting in the future if someone writes/updates a R-package with this modified k-means.